# Add a column from a dataframe using for

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I want to get a table from an url and add a column with the name of the player for each of the tables but when trying I cannot get it done, below code is what I tried, but the insert column does not have anything, basically i get the table for each of the websites but I cannot add the player name column for each of the url.

Can somebody help?? I'm a newbie to python...

```
directory = ['https://fbref.com/en/players/d38fdf53/','https://fbref.com/en/players/773f5f12/', 'https://fbref.com/en/players/54bcdeb0/','https://fbref.com/en/players/f2dd9a21/'

player_name= ['Pervis Estupiñán','Michael Estrada','Gonzalo Plata','Carlos Gruezo']

scrapped_list = []
jugador = []

for i in directory:

url = urlopen(i)
# Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe
df1 = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df1 = df1.dropna()
time.sleep(3) # Sleep for 3 seconds
df1 = np.transpose(df1)

for j in player_name:
   player = player_name.get(j)
   df1.insert(0,"Player",player,True) #Add the player Name       
   break

scrapped_list.append(df1)
df1 = pd.concat(scrapped_list)
print(df1)
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
directory = ['https://fbref.com/en/players/d38fdf53/','https://fbref.com/en/players/773f5f12/', 'https://fbref.com/en/players/54bcdeb0/','https://fbref.com/en/players/f2dd9a21/']

player_name= ['Pervis Estupiñán','Michael Estrada','Gonzalo Plata','Carlos Gruezo']

scrapped_list = []


for url, name in zip(directory, player_name):
    try:
        url_response = urlopen(url)
        # Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe
        df_list = pd.read_html(url_response)
        df1 = df_list[0]
        df1 = df1.dropna()
        df1.set_index('Statistic', inplace=True)
        df_t = df1.T   # transpose dataframe
        df_t['Player'] = name
        scrapped_list.append(df_t)
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(3)  # Sleep for 3 seconds


df_all = pd.concat(scrapped_list)
print(df_all)

"""
Statistic  Non-Penalty Goals  npxG  ... Aerials won            Player
Per 90                  0.00  0.03  ...        1.50  Pervis Estupiñán
Percentile              20.0  43.0  ...        72.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Per 90                  0.31  0.24  ...        2.40   Michael Estrada
Percentile              40.0  17.0  ...        67.0   Michael Estrada
Per 90                  0.00  0.05  ...        1.21     Carlos Gruezo
Percentile              12.0  32.0  ...        51.0     Carlos Gruezo
"""

# or below is what you want

directory = ['https://fbref.com/en/players/d38fdf53/','https://fbref.com/en/players/773f5f12/', 'https://fbref.com/en/players/54bcdeb0/','https://fbref.com/en/players/f2dd9a21/']
player_name= ['Pervis Estupiñán','Michael Estrada','Gonzalo Plata','Carlos Gruezo']
scrapped_list = []

for url, name in zip(directory, player_name):
    try:
        url_response = urlopen(url)
        # Assign the table data to a Pandas dataframe
        df_list = pd.read_html(url_response)
        df1 = df_list[0]
        df1 = df1.dropna()
        df1 = df1.set_index('Statistic').assign(Player=name)
        # df_t = df1.T   # transpose dataframe
        scrapped_list.append(df1)
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(3)  # Sleep for 3 seconds


df_all = pd.concat(scrapped_list)
print(df_all)

"""
                      Per 90  Percentile            Player
Statistic                                                  
Non-Penalty Goals        0.00        20.0  Pervis Estupiñán
npxG                     0.03        43.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Shots Total              0.61        50.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Assists                  0.04        30.0  Pervis Estupiñán
xA                       0.09        53.0  Pervis Estupiñán
npxG+xA                  0.12        44.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Shot-Creating Actions    1.34        24.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Passes Attempted        57.36        66.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Pass Completion %       78.2%        56.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Progressive Passes       3.93        61.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Progressive Carries      4.50        48.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Dribbles Completed       0.97        69.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Touches (Att Pen)        1.58        60.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Progressive Passes Rec   2.92        76.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Pressures               13.62        60.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Tackles                  2.51        73.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Interceptions            3.12        97.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Blocks                   2.11        70.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Clearances               1.91        47.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Aerials won              1.50        72.0  Pervis Estupiñán
Non-Penalty Goals        0.31        40.0   Michael Estrada
npxG                     0.24        17.0   Michael Estrada
Shots Total              1.46         3.0   Michael Estrada
Assists                  0.31        91.0   Michael Estrada
xA                       0.23        88.0   Michael Estrada
npxG+xA                  0.47        42.0   Michael Estrada
Shot-Creating Actions    1.78        20.0   Michael Estrada
Passes Attempted        16.20         6.0   Michael Estrada
Pass Completion %       65.2%         7.0   Michael Estrada
Progressive Passes       1.57        61.0   Michael Estrada
Progressive Carries      2.30        33.0   Michael Estrada
Dribbles Completed       1.05        57.0   Michael Estrada
Touches (Att Pen)        3.14         3.0   Michael Estrada
Progressive Passes Rec   4.81         1.0   Michael Estrada
Pressures               14.01        42.0   Michael Estrada
Tackles                  0.73        50.0   Michael Estrada
Interceptions            0.31        28.0   Michael Estrada
Blocks                   0.42        11.0   Michael Estrada
Clearances               0.42        41.0   Michael Estrada
Aerials won              2.40        67.0   Michael Estrada
Non-Penalty Goals        0.00        12.0     Carlos Gruezo
npxG                     0.05        32.0     Carlos Gruezo
Shots Total              0.93        43.0     Carlos Gruezo
Assists                  0.00        11.0     Carlos Gruezo
xA                       0.01         2.0     Carlos Gruezo
npxG+xA                  0.06         9.0     Carlos Gruezo
Shot-Creating Actions    1.02         8.0     Carlos Gruezo
Passes Attempted        28.95         2.0     Carlos Gruezo
Pass Completion %       80.8%        37.0     Carlos Gruezo
Progressive Passes       2.13         4.0     Carlos Gruezo
Progressive Carries      1.21         1.0     Carlos Gruezo
Dribbles Completed       0.28        10.0     Carlos Gruezo
Touches (Att Pen)        0.74        28.0     Carlos Gruezo
Progressive Passes Rec   0.84        16.0     Carlos Gruezo
Pressures               20.32        68.0     Carlos Gruezo
Tackles                  2.13        43.0     Carlos Gruezo
Interceptions            2.04        75.0     Carlos Gruezo
Blocks                   1.48        45.0     Carlos Gruezo
Clearances               1.67        76.0     Carlos Gruezo
Aerials won              1.21        51.0     Carlos Gruezo

"""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: great.. I was out for some weeks but thank you for all the info, it is great...

Comment: I'm glad to get your reply. If my answer is satisfactory, please click the tick